# Why am I getting this error? "bad operand types for binary operator '>'"

Tags: java, blackjack

I would like to know what it causing the error of "bad operand types for binary operator '>'" down below I have the codes for both my **Hand** and **Card** classes. I've also specified the lines that are causing the error.
Thanks for the help. This is for a BlackJack project.

**Hand** Class

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Hand {

private Vector hand;   // The cards in the hand.

public Hand() {
       // Create a Hand object that is initially empty.
  hand = new Vector();
}

public void clear() {
     // Discard all the cards from the hand.
  hand.removeAllElements();
}

public void addCard(PlayingCard c) {
     // Add the card c to the hand.  c should be non-null.  (If c is
     // null, nothing is added to the hand.)
  if (c != null)
     hand.addElement(c);
}

public void removeCard(PlayingCard c) {
     // If the specified card is in the hand, it is removed.
  hand.removeElement(c);
}

public void removeCard(int position) {
     // If the specified position is a valid position in the hand,
     // then the card in that position is removed.
  if (position >= 0 && position < hand.size())
     hand.removeElementAt(position);
}

public int getCardCount() {
     // Return the number of cards in the hand.
  return hand.size();
}

public PlayingCard getCard(int position) {
      // Get the card from the hand in given position, where positions
      // are numbered starting from 0.  If the specified position is
      // not the position number of a card in the hand, then null
      // is returned.
  if (position >= 0 && position < hand.size())
     return (PlayingCard)hand.elementAt(position);
  else
     return null;
}

 public void sortBySuit() {
     // Sorts the cards in the hand so that cards of the same suit are
     // grouped together, and within a suit the cards are sorted by value.
     // Note that aces are considered to have the lowest value, 1.
  Vector newHand = new Vector();
  while (hand.size() > 0) {
     int pos = 0;  // Position of minimal card.
     PlayingCard c = (PlayingCard)hand.elementAt(0);  // Minumal card.


    for (int i = 1; i < hand.size(); i++) {
        PlayingCard c1 = (PlayingCard)hand.elementAt(i);

        *if ( c1.getCardFace() > c.getCardFace() ||
                (c1.getCardFace().equals(c.getCardFace()) && c1.getFaceValue() < c.getFaceValue()) ) {*
            pos = i;
            c = c1;
        }
     }
     hand.removeElementAt(pos);
     newHand.addElement(c);
  }
  hand = newHand;
}

public void sortByValue() {
     // Sorts the cards in the hand so that cards of the same value are
     // grouped together.  Cards with the same value are sorted by suit.
     // Note that aces are considered to have the lowest value, 1.
  Vector newHand = new Vector();
  while (hand.size() > 0) {
     int pos = 0;  // Position of minimal card.
     PlayingCard c = (PlayingCard)hand.elementAt(0);  // Minumal card.
     for (int i = 1; i < hand.size(); i++) {
        PlayingCard c1 = (PlayingCard)hand.elementAt(i);

        *if ( c1.getFaceValue() < c.getFaceValue() ||
                (c1.getFaceValue() == c.getFaceValue() && c1.getCardFace() > c.getCardFace()) ) {*
            pos = i;
            c = c1;
        }
     }
     hand.removeElementAt(pos);
     newHand.addElement(c);
  }
  hand = newHand;
}

 }
```

The error is in the **hand** class in the lines

```
if ( c1.getCardFace() > c.getCardFace() ||
                (c1.getCardFace().equals(c.getCardFace()) &&     c1.getFaceValue() < c.getFaceValue()) ) {
```

and

```
if ( c1.getFaceValue() < c.getFaceValue() ||
                (c1.getFaceValue() == c.getFaceValue() && c1.getCardFace() > c.getCardFace()) ) {
```

This is the **Card** Class

```
public class PlayingCard
{
// Instance Data - all things common to all cards
private String cardFace; // king, q, j, 10 - 2, A
private int faceValue; // numberic value of the card
private char cardSuit; // hold suit of the card
private char suits[] = {(char)(003), (char)(004), (char)(005), (char)(006)};

// Constructor
public PlayingCard(int value, int suit)
{
    faceValue = value;
    setFace();
    setSuit(suit);
}

// helper setFace()
public void setFace()
{
    switch(faceValue)
    {
        case 1:
            cardFace = "A";
            faceValue = 14;
            break;
        case 11:
            cardFace = "J";
            break;
        case 12:
            cardFace = "Q";
            break;
        case 0:
            cardFace = "K";
            faceValue = 13;
            break;
        default:
            cardFace = ("" + faceValue);
    }
}

public void setSuit(int suit) // suit num between 0 and 3
{
    cardSuit = suits[suit];
}

// other helpers
public int getFaceValue()
{
    return faceValue;
}
public String getCardFace()
{
    return cardFace;
}

public String toString()
{
    return (cardFace + cardSuit);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getCardFace()` returns a String. `<` and `>` operators exist only for numeric types.

You can use `c1.getCardFace().compareTo(c.getCardFace()) < 0` or  `c1.getCardFace().compareTo(c.getCardFace()) > 0` instead, to compare the Strings according to their natural ordering.

```
if ( c1.getCardFace() > c.getCardFace() ||
                (c1.getCardFace().equals(c.getCardFace()) &&     c1.getFaceValue() < c.getFaceValue()) ) {
```

would become

```
if ( c1.getCardFace().compareTo(c.getCardFace()) > 0 ||
                (c1.getCardFace().equals(c.getCardFace()) &&     c1.getFaceValue() < c.getFaceValue()) ) {
```

and

```
if ( c1.getFaceValue() < c.getFaceValue() ||
                (c1.getFaceValue() == c.getFaceValue() && c1.getCardFace() > c.getCardFace()) ) {
```

would become

```
if ( c1.getFaceValue() < c.getFaceValue() ||
                (c1.getFaceValue() == c.getFaceValue() && c1.getCardFace().compareTo(c.getCardFace()) > 0) ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

`getCardFace()` is returning String value but you can't use `< , > , <= or >=` for comparing String.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use these operators `<`,`>` and `==` to compare two Strings, instead use `compareTo` method.

From [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> **public int compareTo(String anotherString)**
>
> Compares two strings ***lexicographically***. The comparison is based on the
>   `Unicode` value of each character in the strings. The character sequence
>   represented by this String object is compared lexicographically to the
>   character sequence represented by the argument string. The result is a
>   negative integer if this String object lexicographically precedes the
>   argument string. The result is a positive integer if this String
>   object lexicographically follows the argument string. The result is
>   zero if the strings are equal; `compareTo` returns `0` exactly when the
>   `equals(Object)` method would return `true`.

An example of comparing two Strings

```
String s1="example1", s2="example2";
if ( s1.compareTo(s2) > 0 )
     System.out.println("First string is greater than second.");
else if ( s1.compareTo(s2) < 0 )
      System.out.println("First string is smaller than second.");
else   
      System.out.println("Both strings are equal.");
```

**Note:** The `compareTo` method is case sensitive i.e "java" and "Java" are two different strings if you use `compareTo` method. String "java" is greater than "Java" as ASCII value of 'j' is greater than 'J'. If you wish to compare strings but ignoring the case then use `compareToIgnoreCase` method.

> **public int compareToIgnoreCase(String str)**
>
> Compares two strings ***lexicographically***, ignoring case differences.
>   This method returns an integer whose sign is that of calling `compareTo`
>   with normalized versions of the strings where case differences have
>   been eliminated by calling
>   `Character.toLowerCase(Character.toUpperCase(character))` on each
>   character.